# Waiting for two http requests hangs until some timeout

Tags: http, flutter

I want to make two http requests and handle the results in flutter.
So, i fetch to urls and tried to use a FutureBuilder to wait for both of them like so:

```
List<T> convertList<T>(List list, T convert(dynamic d)) {
  List<T> result = new List<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(convert(list[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

Future<List<Team>> fetchTeams() async {
  final response = await http
        .get("https://some/api/teams");
  List responseJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
  return convertList(responseJson, (d) => Team.fromJson(d));
}

Future<List<Player>> fetchPlayers() async {
  final response = await http
        .get("https://some/api/players");
  List responseJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
  return convertList(responseJson, (d) => Player.fromJson(d));
}

new FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.wait([fetchPlayers(), fetchTeams()]),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // .. handling the content
  })
```

The problem is that the fetching players http call "never" returns; and with never i mean just after 5 minutes or so. After the timeout, the data is available! 
When I only fetch players without the teams, the request returns immediately. Both endpoints point to an azure service and are both available and running.

Any hints to that issue?

Comment: before and after `await`ed `http.get()` requests add two `print` statements, like: `print('teams++'); await http.get(...); print('teams--')` - do the same for players, what do you see?

Comment: @pskink hmm, you right, it prints both teams-- and players-- ... but the builder callback is not called, at least not really reliable

Comment: try for testing  `Future.wait([fetchPlayers(), fetchTeams()]).then((lst) => print('========== $lst ========));`, do you see anything?

Comment: and of course comment out `FutureBuilder` for a while...

Comment: so is `then()` method called?